# Why does Foundation seem to trash RequireJS modules?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, zurb-foundation

My HTML is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script data-main="/static/scripts/main" src="/static/scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

`static/scripts/main` looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "foundation": '/static/scripts/foundation-6/js/foundation.min'
    }
});    

require(["foundation", "moduleA"], function(foundation, moduleA) {
    console.log("main.js loaded dependencies");
});
```

And `static/scripts/moduleA.js` is:

```
console.log("ModuleA loaded");

define(function() {    
    console.log("inside moduleA callback");
    return {
        Blah: "Blah!"
    }    
});
```

I can see that the `moduleA.js` script gets loaded by `require`, but it is not being treated as a module and I see from the console that the inner callback is never executed. A breakpoint in the `console.log` line in `main.js` shows that what gets returned as `moduleA` is not the module I would expect but instead an instance of `Interchange(element, options)` while the returned `foundation` object is an instance of `Abide(element, options)`. These seem to be Foundation components but I don't see why they're being returned here.

But, say I then remove the Foundation dependency by changing the require statement in `main.js` to this:

```
require(["moduleA"], function(moduleA) {
    console.log("main.js loaded dependencies");
});
```

Running that makes everything work as expected - I now see the "inside moduleA callback" message in the console, and a breakpoint shows that my `moduleA` object contains a Blah member, as intended.

What is going on here? How is Foundation intercepting this require() call and returning something unwanted? Is there a different way I should be including Foundation into this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should figure out that foundation library is AMD module. You should open foundation.js and try to found this code at the beginning:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {
    // [1] AMD anonymous module
    define(['exports', 'require'], factory);
}
```

So foundation.js is not AMD module. RequireJS has [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) option for non-AMD modules. Next you should check what variable foundation returns to Global Scope. At [302](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.js) line you can see this code: `window.Foundation = Foundation;`. Global variable is `Foundation`. result code should be:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "foundation":   'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.0/foundation',     
    },
    shim:{
        "foundation":{
            exports:"Foundation"
        }
    }
});
```

But unfortunately for foundation.js is not enough. At [303](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.js) line you can see that foundation.js is jquery plugin. So you should include jquery via RequireJS. jQuery is AMD module. You can see it inside file. You should include jQuery in shim as dependency for foundation.js. So result code will be:

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "foundation":   'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.0/foundation',
        "jquery":       "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1"
    },
    shim:{
        "foundation":{
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports:"Foundation"
        }
    }
});  

require(["foundation", "moduleA"], function(foundation,moduleA) {
    debugger;
    console.log("main.js loaded dependencies");
});
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script data-main="main.js" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js">  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

moduleA.js is same.

ps: I will be grateful if you fix my grammatical errors.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's it. At some point I thought I read that Foundation could just be required this way, and the source code does mention AMD near the top, but obviously it can't, and somehow it manages to trample all over the module system as well. I'll leave this open a little longer to see if anybody answers that aspect.